# Confusion about "type" and "data" in haskell

Tags: haskell, types

```
data MoneyAmount = Amount Float Currency
     deriving (Show, Eq)
data Currency = EUR | GBP | USD | CHF 
     deriving (Show, Eq)     
type Account = (Integer, MoneyAmount)

putAmount :: MoneyAmount -> Account -> Account
putAmount mon acc = undefined
```

I need to write a function that adds money to an account (display error if money added is wrong currency in account).

I know how to create an Amount

```
let moni = Amount 6.6 EUR
```

but i have no idea what to write to create an Account? (i hope that sentence makes sense) I don't know how to manipulate the input to do the whole add to account thing.

I've tried things like

```
let acc = Account 1 moni
```

My question is more how to manipulate the Account so I can write the function.

Answer (score 6):

`type` creates a *type synonym*; an `Account` is exactly the same as an `(Integer, MoneyAmount)`, and you write it the same way:

```
let acc = (1, moni)
```

Comment: aw sweet, thanks. How would I use acc in the function then? I presume simply doing acc + money (let money= Amount 5 EUR) wouldn't work.

Comment: Not quite, but you can do `let (accountNo, amount) = acc`, or not write `acc` at all and write `putAmount mon (accountNo, amount)` or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

A `type` is just an alias.  It doesn't define a new type but instead a new name for an existing type.  So you could do

```
type Money = Float
```

And you can use `Money` where ever you can use a `Float` and vice-versa.  If you had

```
foo :: Float -> Float
foo x = 2 * x
```

Then

```
> foo (1 :: Float)
2
> foo (1 :: Money)
2
```

Both work fine.  In your case, `Account` is just an alias for `(Integer, MoneyAmount)`, so you would construct one just as you would any other tuple.

A `data` defines an entirely new type, and this requires new constructors.  For example:

```
data Bool = False | True
```

defines the `Bool` type with the constructors `False` and `True`.  A more complicated example would be

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

which defines the `Maybe a` polymorphic type with constructors `Nothing :: Maybe a` and `Just :: a -> Maybe a`.  I've included the types of these constructors to highlight that they exist as normal values and functions.  The difference between a function and a constructor is that you can do anything you want in a function, but a constructor is only allowed to take existing values and make a value of another type without performing any transformations to it.  Constructors are just wrappers around values.